# AmCharts animated line on map chart

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to use amCharts for create connection map.

I take this demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines

But, I want to have a growing line instead of an plane. Can this be implemented?

```
var planeImage = plane.createChild(am4core.Sprite);
planeImage.scale = 0.08;
planeImage.horizontalCenter = "middle";
planeImage.verticalCenter = "middle";
planeImage.path = "m2,106h28l24,30h72l-44,-133h35l80,132h98c21,0 21,34 0,34l-98,0 -80,134h-35l43,-133h-71l-24,30h-28l15,-47";
planeImage.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(2).brighten(-0.2);
planeImage.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by growing line? You want to draw a curved line between two locations and animate the creation of this line between the two points?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The line between two coordinates. Line instead of an airplane from example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be closed.
I found solution from documentation: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/animating-map-lines-with-css/